# Cordova 2.0.0 Error OSX

Tags: command-line-interface, cordova, osx-mountain-lion, cordova-2.0.0

## Cordova 2.0.0 Error OSX

Calling: `sudo ./create ~/cordovatest com.christopherdebeer.test01 testapp` *

- When in the `/bin/` folder of `Cordova-2.0.0` dmg unpacked from `phonegap-phonegap-2.0.0-0-g2dbbdab.zip`

Returns the following error:

```
/Volumes/Cordova-2.0.0/bin/replaces: line 28: tmpFile: Read-only file system mv: tmpFile: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer from #phonegap on freenode

I was trying to run the `./create` file while it was still in the `.dmg` file. Copying to my home directory etc fixed the problem.

Thanks to @michi_ on #phonegap at freenode.net for the answer.